# Masonry : undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, masonry

I know what the `undefined is not a function` error means, but I don't get why it is showing up here.

I just downloaded the last Masonry version and tried to follow the docs. (http://desandro.github.io/masonry/docs/methods.html)

The layout is working fine, but it seems like I can't use any `masonry()` function at all. Always getting the `undefined is not a function` error on my `masonry()` calls.

Since the layout is working, I'm assuming the masonry script is working fine, then **why can't I use `masonry(...)` without this undefined function error** ?

(I searched about changes from Masonry v2 to Masonry v3, but didn't find anything related to this function)

Partial HTML code :

```
<a class="navbar-brand" id ="test-masonry" href="#">...</a>

<div id="masonry-container" class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 330, "itemSelector": ".item" }'>
    <div class="item">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createNewBlock">Create a new block</button> 
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Freshly downloaded from the official Masonry website -->
<script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/appCtrl.js"></script>

<!--  Copied from the example in the docs -->
<script>
$(function(){
    var $container = $('#masonry-container');
    $('#test-masonry').click(function(){
        var $boxes = $('<div>Test !</div>');
        $container.prepend( $boxes ).masonry( 'reload' );
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are loading Masonry before jQuery, hence why you are getting `undefined`. When including masonry, it check if jQuery is loaded. In case it is, it will set the Masonry property to the jQuery object : `$.fn.masonry`. So when you load Masonry before jQuery, you are not allowed to use `jQObject.masonry()`.

The layout is working fine because Masonry doesnt need jQuery to work

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Not sure how I could be "loading jQuery twice" however, might be related to Angular and jQLite ?

Comment: Can't tell, maybe your are using a CMS?

Comment: Nop. Masonry, JQuery, AngularJS and Bootstrap. That's it. Nevermind, it's working now.

Comment: @ClémentMalet be nice to know how you got it to work to aid others with a similar issue - I'm having the same issue using bootstrap

Comment: @fidev Exactly what is wrote in the answer. I was loading Masonry before jQuery, so I moved it down so it gets loaded **after** jQuery and it worked.